# How to render direction on the specific area of the map

Tags: google-maps

I use this code for display directions (route on the map)

```
var rendererOptions = { draggable: true };
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
settings.directionsDisplay = directionsDisplay;
directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('gmapPanel'));
```

How to render direction on the specific area of the map? I need that directions was zoomed and offset from left and top panel and displays it inside the selected area of the map

Details in the screen:
[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to prevent the DirectionsRenderer from zooming the map to fit the directions? ([preserveViewport](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions))

Comment: No, I want that line (route) will be shown only in the area where I highlighted with black border.
Currently default behaviour is that line (route) go behind transparent panels and it looks bad